# List inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an ArrayList of Items that i wanna show to ListView

```
class CoursesItem {
    String Recipe_name;
    String[] Ingredient_name;
    float[] amount;
    String[] Unit_name;} 
    //(Notice that it has ONE recipe_name and MANY informations)
```

The problem is i don't know how to show all informations of CoursesItem like this:
[image]

I know already try ListView inside a ListView and that is not an opition

Comment: What about using ExpandableListView? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Use ExpandableListView

Comment: Use ExpandableListView http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/

Comment: that's exactly what i need! thanks you guys so much!